# Запуск python скрипта в случае запуска какой либо программы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мониторинг запуска программы с помощью python.
Пробовала так :

```
import subprocess
import time


while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    if subprocess.Popen("zathura", shell=True):
        print("Zathura app was started.Let's do something...")
    else:
        print("Nothing interesting.")
```

Comment: И что выдает такой код? _даже интересно каким путем вы пришли к нему, решая свою задачу_

Comment: Запускает затуру каждую секунду. А хотела чтобы скрипт проверял запущена ли она.

Comment: Правильно. Потому что документация говорит нам, что Popen выполняет программу в новом процессе. Чтобы проверить, запущена ли программа, нужно смотреть ее наличие в запущенных процессах. Какая система? Виндовс?

Comment: Система Debian Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать модуль [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/).

```
import psutil

processes = psutil.process_iter() # get all running processes
for p in processes:
    if "zathura" in p.name(): 
         # zathura is running
```

Больше примеров: [Filtering and sorting processes](http://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#filtering-and-sorting-processes).

Comment: так можно NoSuchProcess  получить. Посмотрите на корректный [примеры использования process_iter() в документации](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#psutil.process_iter)