# Как получить путь до запущенного процесса?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Можно ли как-то получить полный путь до запущенного процесса? Например запущен cmd.exe и я получаю откуда он запущен?

Comment: Какой путь? Curdir, каталог с exe, каталог, откуда он запущен?

Comment: Запущен foo.py и cmd.exe, foo.py должен определить откуда запущен(или где лежит) cmd.exe

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону модуля `psutil`. В нём есть класс `psutil.Process`, у которого есть метод `cwd()` для получения полной рабочей директории процесса и, например, `cmdline()` для получения собственно строки, с помощью которой запущен процесс. Скорее всего, этого хватит для поиска пути. С помощью `psutil.process_iter()` можно пройтись по процессам. http://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ Не имею доступа к windows, поэтому точнее сказать не могу, но psutil кросплатформенный.

Comment: Можно пример кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи модуля [psutil](http://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) можно сделать так:

```
import psutil # pip install psutil

proc_name = 'top' #'cmd.exe'

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    # Пока скрипт работает, процесс уже может перестать существовать
    # (поскольку между psutil.process_iter() и proc.name() проходит время)
    # и будет выброшено исключение psutil.NoSuchProcess
    try:
        proc_name_in_loop = proc.name()
    except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
        pass
    else:
        if proc_name_in_loop == proc_name:
            print(proc.cwd())
            print(proc.exe())
```

При этом `proc.cwd()` выведет рабочую директорию процесса, а `proc.exe()` - путь к исполняемому файлу. Ещё может быть полезным список, который возвращает `proc.cmdline()`: так, например, когда я у себя запускаю скрипт на питоне, записанный в file_name.py, результат такой:

```
['python3', 'file_name.py']
```

В частности, его можно использовать, если несколько запущенных процессов имеют одно имя, но разные аргументы

---

**P.S.** этот ответ для третьей версии питона в Linux, я лишён возможности проверить на втором питоне или windows, но суть не должна измениться

Comment: Чтобы учесть возможное NoSuchProcess исключение, адаптируйте [код из документации process_iter() метода.](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#psutil.process_iter). Аналогичная [проблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/863125/23044)