# Python || При попытке сравнить названия процессов происходит ошибка

Tags: python

Имею некоторый скрипт, который должен будет отслеживать запущенные процессы, но при попытке сравнить названия процессов из заранее подготовленного массива и из `psutil.process_iter()` вылетает ошибка.

Код:

```
import psutil

process = ['taskmgr.exe', 'tm.exe', 'systemexplorer.exe', 'tmx.exe', 'tmx64.exe']

for name in psutil.process_iter():
    processName = name.name().lower()
    for y in process:
        if(y == processName):
            return(False)
return(True)
```

Ошибка:

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Если честно, я пока не понял, откуда берётся ошибка, но тут есть общий момент, что процесс мог перестать существовать уже после того, как вызван `process_iter()`, поэтому нужно ловить исключение `psutil.NoSuchProcess` (https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#psutil.process_iter)

Comment: В ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/864112/247581 с подсказки jfs это сделано

Comment: Да, сработало, спасибо за ваш ответ!